# Function problems in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-module

I'm a beginner in Angular and I have a problem with the functions. I have a simple code. In that there are two alerts to probe they are not getting called.

**HTML**

```
<div data-ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <form novalidate class="simple-form">
      Last name: 
      <input type="text" name="lname" data-ng-model="product.name"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-ng-click="mandar()" >
   </form>
   <button ng-click="mandar()">Remove</button>
</div>
```

My JavaScript:

```
var app =angular.module('pdbApp');
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $window) {

$window.alert('I am here!');


$scope.mandar=function(){
  $window.alert('Hi there!');

  };    
});
```

I also have the app.js

```
    angular
    .module('pdbApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
         $routeProvider
         .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
           controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })
  .when('/about', {
    templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
    controller: 'AboutCtrl'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
  });
```

And also my index.html

```
 <html class="no-js">
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
<!-- endbuild -->

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- endbuild -->


<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.2/angular.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body ng-app="pdbApp">

  <div class="container">
    <div data-ng-view=""></div>
  </div>


  <!-- Libraries -->
  <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- Some Bootstrap Helper Libraries -->

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/underscore.min.js"></script>
<!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
<script src="js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
```

When I press the mandar button doesn't happen anything.
Can anybody tell me why it is no working?

Comment: do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: is it your first module declaration?

Comment: where is your `ng-app` declared?

Comment: can you explain **what** not working?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you add `ng-app="pdbApp"` on your page to tell angular to run on the page. Also make sure you have added the `angular.js` file on the page.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-app="pdbApp" data-ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <form novalidate class="simple-form">
     Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" data-ng-model="product.name"><br>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-ng-click="mandar()" >
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: @Lzarra does it helped you:?

Answer (score 1):

without any stack trace all we can do is speculate. But as others have said you need to include `ng-app` within your template so angular knows the scope of the HTML for that app. Also you need `ng-controller` so angular knows the scope of your controller in the HTML.

However these are all basic things covered in all tutorials, the thing your doing that isn't covered in most is your app definition. This will cause your app to fail if it isn't intentional.

Your doing

`var app =angular.module('pdbApp');`

This tells angular 'find me an existing application called `pdbApp`'. However is this is your first decliration of that app your need to tell angular to create it.

You do that by adding an array:

`var app =angular.module('pdbApp', []);`

The array contains a list of application dependencies if you have any.